# trying to figure out weirdness with aws listObjects call

Tags: amazon-s3

I am noticing some strange behaviors when trying to build functions around the aws-sdk S3 listobjects method.  Specifically I'm trying to convert an old unix-filesystem tool that had folders with each customer's id for their  uploaded images.

I've already written in tools that allow the user to create 'directories' which basically does the same thing the amazon S3 web gui does, creating an object with a trailing delimeter. (e.g. 'myfolder/', in this case under the userid such as '12345/myfolder/')

Since we are migrating existing images to this server, we used a snowball to transfer the almost 10Tb of files on our current co-located server. I'm not sure if this process creates items differently, but I'm seeing some weird behavior from listObjects when trying to detect the directories.

In my test folder, I have a subfolder that was created by the snowball import and one that I created. When I do a listObjects, I get a list item for my subfolder with a trailing '/' delimiter, but I do not get one for the snowball subfolder with a trailing '/'.

The subfolder has an object in it, the folder I created did not when I first noticed this behavior. As I was trying to figure out what was going on, I tried specifying a Delimiter in the params, but then I only saw objects (no sub-folders at all). So I was working on a way to regex a full listing with a given prefix and trying to parse any subfolders out of the paths that had .+/.* in them when I noticed that a subfolder I created 'under' my test folder 'with' a file in it had an entry ending in '/' (unlike the snowball folder)

I know, it's hard to picture, so let me give a basic layout:

when I first noticed it, this is what files existed:

```
12345/snowballdir/someimage.jpg
12345/test/
```

ListObjectsV2 (no delimiter, prefix "of 12345/") returned info for:

```
12345/snowballdir/someimage.jpg
12345/test/
```

Now what I'm seeing is files of:

```
12345/snowballdir/someimage.jpg
12345/test/foo/someimage.jpg
12345/test/bar/
12345/test/anotherimage.jpg
```

getting the result:

```
12345/snowballdir/someimage.jpg
12345/test/
12345/test/foo/
12345/test/foo/someimage.jpg
12345/test/bar/
12345/test/anotherimage.jpg
```

Note: no 12345/snowballdir/ included in the results

Does it only show the directory if the directory in a listObjects if it was created independent of an object being created within it? Is there any way I can 'fix' this for the ones that aren't showing if so?

Answer (score 0):

I revisited this issue today as it occurred to me while finishing up our user-interface (file uploader/manager) that if a user deletes a file created by the snowball import (where empty objects were 'not' created representing any directories delimited in the Key name), if it is the last object representing a given directory structure, that directory structure essentially ceases to exist!

I did some testing using the SDK and confirmed my suspicions. If I create an empty object to represent the directory then create an object within it, deleting the object does not delete the directory represented by the empty object with a trailing delimiter. But if I create an object without creating an empty 'directory' object first, deleting that object removes any evidence that the 'directory path' ever existed.

I also confirmed that  you can create the 'empty' directory representation after the fact it will not effect any objects containing the [pseudo] directory in it's key name. But deleting all objects containing that 'path' will not remove the existence of the directory.

So it seems, either I have to create a work-around in any and all 'delete' functions that will check if it contains a 'directory' representation and create an empty object representing it's folder if it does not already exist before deleting the object, or I am going to have to go through the entire system and create empty objects for any and all objects that appear to be in 'folders' as a result of their keyname.

Ugh, it would be nice if AWS documented this somewhere. I don't immediately see anything in the snowball documentation that makes it clear this is the case.

A few other ramifications of this:

It is possible to create an object representing a file in a [pseudo] directory such as:

```
myfolder/path/myfile.txt
```

Then create another object that appears to use the same name as a folder:

```
myfolder/path/myfile.txt/anotherfile.txt
```

It is even possible to create a [pseudo]directory placeholder"

```
myfolder/path/myfile.txt/
```

It should also be noted that since the directories do not actually exist (unless you create a placeholder to represent their existence) that if you have a long path represented in an object key, such as:

```
some/really/long/path/myfile.txt
```

That the following 'directories' don't actually exist if you do not implicitly create them:

```
some/
some/really/
some/really/long/
some/really/long/path/
```

Which means if you delete that object, any trace of those 'directories' without placeholders (or other objects representing the same pseudo-path) cease to exist!

It should also be noted that if you wanted to delete anything represented as a sub path of that pseudo-tree, such as deleting everything under "some/really/*" you would have to use the utility SDK function: deleteMatchingObjects with the prefix "some/really"* or "some/really/" or an equivalent regex. Just doing a 'deleteObject" for "some/really/" will only remove any existing placeholder with the key "some/really" and won't track down and remove files such as the example above.

NOTE: the "some/really" without the trailing slash might match other files such as "some/reallybig.jpg"

SW

Addendum:
Rather than going through the entire bucket creating placeholders for every pseudo-directory represented in a key name, I realized the only time it will be a potential problem is when deleting an object that includes in it's key name the representation of a path. If I then test and create an 'parent' directory whenever an object with a key representing a file in a sub-directory, I can preserve the emulation of those folders, as trying to delete the 'parent' created when an object was deleted will then test and create any additional parents until no more parent directories are represented in the key 'path'.

the below function allows you to pass the original key, then uses a regex to find any sub directories (assumes a unix 'forward slash' delimiter):

```
/**
 * run prior to a delete to preserve any directories represented in the
 *   pathname due to the 'flat' nature of the S3 filesystem.
 * Checks if the 'key' represents a file in a 'pseudo' directory.
 *   If yes, it checks if an empty placeholder exists for the directory.
 *   If no, it creates one to preserve the directory in the bucket.
 * @param string $target
 * @param null|string $bucket
 * @return \Aws\Result|S3Exception|\Exception
 */
private function _preDeletePersistSubdir($target, $bucket=null) {
    if(preg_match('#^([^/]+.*/)[^/]+/?$#', $target, $m)) {
        $subDir = $m[1];
        try {
            if((!$this->getS3ClientCached()->doesObjectExist($bucket,$subDir))) {
                $params = array(
                    "Bucket" => $bucket,
                    "Key" => $subDir,
                    "Body" => ""
                );
                return $putDirResult = $this->getS3ClientCached()->putObject( $params );
            }
        } catch(S3Exception $e) { return $e; }
    }
}
```

Similarly, you could recursively build the entire tree with a similar function changing the 'if' on the preg_match to a 'while' being sure to assign $target = $subDir at the end of each loop:

```
/**
 * @param string $target
 * @param null|string $bucket
 * @return \Aws\Result|S3Exception|\Exception
 */
private function createSubdirPlaceholders($target, $bucket=null) {
    while(preg_match('#^([^/]+.*/)[^/]+/?$#', $target, $m)) {
        $subDir = $m[1];
        try {
            if((!$this->getS3ClientCached()->doesObjectExist($bucket,$subDir))) {
                $params = array(
                    "Bucket" => $bucket,
                    "Key" => $subDir,
                    "Body" => ""
                );
                return $putDirResult = $this->getS3ClientCached()->putObject( $params );
            }
        } catch(S3Exception $e) { return $e; }
        $target = $subDir;
    }
}
```

Comment: replace $this->getS3ClientCached with whatever your createS3() value may be.